# Delete all marks except bookmarks in nvim

Tags: neovim, autocmd, mark

I use [dashboard](https://github.com/glepnir/dashboard-nvim) so I like my marks clean.
So I generally make many marks while working on something and then delete them all except the file bookmark in the end. Is there any way to delete all marks **except the bookmarks or the uppercase letters**. So is there a way to clear all marks when opening nvim.
*btw I use [marks.nvim](https://github.com/chentau/marks.nvim) so any config options for this will also be accepted*

Minimal init.vim

```
call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/plugged_minimal')
Plug 'chentau/marks.nvim'
Plug 'juneggun/fzf.vim'
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'do': { -> fzf#install() } }
Plug 'glepnir/dashboard-nvim', { 'on': 'Dashboard' }
"code runner

call plug#end()
lua << EOF
require'marks'.setup {
  -- whether to map keybinds or not. default true
  default_mappings = true,
  -- which builtin marks to show. default {}
  builtin_marks = { ".", "<", ">", "^" },
  -- whether movements cycle back to the beginning/end of buffer. default true
  cyclic = true,
  -- whether the shada file is updated after modifying uppercase marks. default false
  force_write_shada = true,
  -- how often (in ms) to redraw signs/recompute mark positions. 
  -- higher values will have better performance but may cause visual lag, 
  -- while lower values may cause performance penalties. default 150.
  refresh_interval = 250,
  -- sign priorities for each type of mark - builtin marks, uppercase marks, lowercase
  -- marks, and bookmarks.
  -- can be either a table with all/none of the keys, or a single number, in which case
  -- the priority applies to all marks.
  -- default 10.
  sign_priority = { lower=10, upper=15, builtin=8, bookmark=20 },
  -- disables mark tracking for specific filetypes. default {}
  excluded_filetypes = {},
  -- marks.nvim allows you to configure up to 10 bookmark groups, each with its own
  -- sign/virttext. Bookmarks can be used to group together positions and quickly move
  -- across multiple buffers. default sign is '!@#$%^&*()' (from 0 to 9), and
  -- default virt_text is "".
  bookmark_0 = {
    sign = "⚑",
    virt_text = "hello world"
  },
  mappings = {}
}
EOF
" misc
set termguicolors
lua require 'colorizer'.setup()
let g:loaded_python_provider = 0
let g:python3_host_prog  = '/usr/bin/python3.9'
set background=dark " use dark mode
" set highlight duration time to 1000 ms, i.e., 1 second
let g:highlightedyank_highlight_duration = 1000
set encoding=utf-8
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set textwidth=79
set expandtab
set autoindent
set fileformat=unix
set signcolumn=yes
set updatetime=300
nmap <Leader>ss :<C-u>SessionSave<CR>
nmap <Leader>sl :<C-u>SessionLoad<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>fh :DashboardFindHistory<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>ff :DashboardFindFile<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>tc :DashboardChangeColorscheme<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>fa :DashboardFindWord<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>fb :DashboardJumpMark<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>cn :DashboardNewFile<CR>
let g:dashboard_default_executive='fzf'
if eval("@%") == ""
    Dashboard
endif
```

[my full init.vim](https://pastebin.com/6LwNV6N1)

Comment: I have no idea what bookmarks are and how they are supposed to be different than simple marks. But if you want to get rid of marks, I suppose you should remove storing them in the viminfo/shada file. And then you could run something like `:delmarks a-z` in an VimEnter autocommand or even `:delmarks!`

Comment: Are you running vim or neovim?  If the latter, then there's a bug that may be causing the marks to not persist deleted.  https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/4295

Answer (score 0):

I would proposes to add to your `init.vim` the following commands to automatically delete the number marks when you enter neovim.

`autocmd VimEnter * delmarks 0-9`

Comment: The command does not work. But when i run ``` delmarks 0-9 ``` then they work

Comment: This still does not work.

Comment: still not working

Comment: It works for me. I'm not sure how to help you. Maybe it is the interaction of plugins. Can you prepare a minimal init.vim that reproduce the problem?

Comment: Added minimal init.vim

Comment: Can you confirm that with that minimal init.vim if you add at the end the line I indicate, restart Neovim and type the command :mark you still see the 0-9 marks (I do not :-|)

Comment: The above fix works for the minimal but not for my full fledged init.vim

Comment: It seems to me that some of your plugin rebuilt the marks. I would put the suggested line at the end of the .init.vim file it it is not enough I would try to find the culprit plugin by reinserting them one by one :-|

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134500/discussion-between-vivian-de-smedt-and-muppi090909).

Answer (score 0):

The marks 0 to 9 are automatically created by vim and stored in the viminfo.
If you don't want that behavior add the following command to your `init.vim`

`set viminfo+=f0`

Comment: This command is not saving the bookmarks.